# How to construct List of objects inside linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 classes: `Master`, `Link` and `User`.

Master can have many User which are connected through Link object to it.

I also have following ViewModel

```
public class ShareLinkUserViewModel
{
    public int MasterID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string UserNBK { get; set; }
    public List<User> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

Using following LINQ, I want to join the Master to Link and User and create an instance of `ShareLinkUserViewModel`

```
var result =
    from master in db.Masters

    join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID into mst_lnk
    from link in mst_lnk

    join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into lnk_usr
    from users in lnk_usr

    select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
    {
        MasterID = master.ID,
        Category = master.Category,
        Subscribers = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                NBK = users.NBK,
                Username = users.Username,
                Email = users.Email
            }
        }
    };

return result.Single();
```

The last line supposed to return a single objects which is type of `ShareLinkUserViewModel`
On the last line I get error below:

> The entity or complex type 'ProMon.Models.User' cannot be constructed
>   in a LINQ to Entities query

**Update**

This is my model:

```
public partial class Master
{
    public Master()
    {
        Links = new HashSet<Link>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}

public partial class Link
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LinkMasterID { get; set; }
    public string UserNBK { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public string NBK { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is User class?

Comment: No sure if it help. It is a class with 3 fields: NBK, Username and Email.

Comment: could you post the models? would like to see their relation

Comment: I added my model. hope this makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't link_users already a collection of Users? I would think that by adding the additional `from link_users` are are attempting to create a new `ShareLinkUserViewModel` for each user with a list of a single user in it.

```
var result =
    from master in db.Masters
    join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID into mst_lnk

    from link in mst_lnk
    join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into lnk_usr

    select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
    {
        MasterID = master.ID,
        Category = master.Category,
        Subscribers = lnk_usr.ToList()
    };
```

In fact, if you just want a single master, why bother grouping by links:

```
var result =
    from master in db.Masters
    join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID    
    join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into users
    select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
    {
        MasterID = master.ID,
        Category = master.Category,
        Subscribers = users.ToList()
    };
```

Comment: Yeah, my linq statement was wrong. This one worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement, you are creating a new list with incorrect syntax. When you initialize a list or object, you need to use the () parenthesis

```
Subscribers = new List<User>() // <--- open close parens are missing
        {
            new User() // <--- here as well...
            {
                NBK = users.NBK,
                Username = users.Username,
                Email = users.Email
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your query as below:

```
var result =
    from master in db.Masters
    join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID into mst_lnk

    from link in mst_lnk
    join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into lnk_usr

    from users in lnk_usr // users is not collection. poor variable name!!! lnk_usr is collection.

    select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
    {
        MasterID = master.ID,
        Category = master.Category,
        Subscribers = lnk_usr.AsQueryable().Select(u => new User
                    {
                        NBK = users.NBK,
                        Username = users.Username,
                        Email = users.Email
                    }).ToList()
    };
```

**UPDATE**: since lnk_usr is also of type User collection, could you just try saying `Subscribers = lnk_usr` as shown below:

```
var result =
        from master in db.Masters
        join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID into mst_lnk

        from link in mst_lnk
        join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into lnk_usr

        from users in lnk_usr // users is not collection. poor variable name!!! lnk_usr is collection.

        select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
        {
            MasterID = master.ID,
            Category = master.Category,
            Subscribers = lnk_usr
        };
```

Comment: @FLICKER since lnk_usr is also of type User, instead of re-populating it, could you just try `Subscribers = lnk_usr`. Please post your observations after making that change.

Answer (score 0):

> The entity or complex type 'ProMon.Models.User' cannot be constructed
>   in a LINQ to Entities query

It means you cannot do "new Entity()" inside a query. Mapped entities cannot be projected.
You should create another class for it:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string NBK { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var result =
    from master in db.Masters

    join lnk in db.LinkUsers on master.ID equals lnk.MasterID into mst_lnk
    from link in mst_lnk

    join usr in db.Users on link.UserNBK equals usr.NBK into lnk_usr
    from users in lnk_usr

    select new ShareLinkUserViewModel
    {
        MasterID = master.ID,
        Category = master.Category,
        Subscribers = new List<UserModel>
        {
            new UserModel
            {
                NBK = users.NBK,
                Username = users.Username,
                Email = users.Email
            }
        }
    };

return result.Single();
```